# Issue in list comprehension to get the count

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dict as:

```
d = [{'status': u'Working', 'name': u'AR000001'}, {'status': u'Working', 'name': u'AR000002'}, {'status': u'Working', 'name': u'AR000003'},{'status': u'Working', 'name': u'AR000013'}]
```

I want to count the working items here using status key

I tried this using **for loop**, which is working fine:

```
print "total",len(d)
wcount = 0

for i in d:
  if i['status'] == "Working":
    wcount += 1


print "working count",wcount
```

But I was missing something here by using list comprehension:

```
count = [sum(li) for li in d if li['status'] == 'Working']
print count
```

**Error:**

```
count = [sum(li) for li in d if li['status'] == 'Working']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sum(li)`, you are attempting to add the dictionary keys to the default int 0 starting value provided by `sum`; dictionaries will *naturally* supply their keys when iterated on.

You can instead apply sum on the bool value from the comparison, which is easily coerced to 1 for `True` or 0 for `False`:

```
count = sum(li['status'] == 'Working' for li in d)
```

Comment: Oh...simple list. Thanks I went much in complications.Will accept  the answer after some hours. Thanks again

Comment: Good solution m8.

Answer (score 2):

One liner.

```
>>> sum(1 for dictionary in dictionaries if dictionary['status'] == 'Working')
4
```

Cool `reduce` alternative (*one-pass*).

```
>>> print reduce(lambda count, dictionary: count + (dictionary['status'] == 'Working'), dictionaries, 0)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be roughly equivalent to the loop below:

```
count = sum([1 for li in d if li['status'] == 'Working'])
```

You get the error above since li would be assigned to each element that matches in the original data structure